# Is there any way to dynamically export functions from a DLL at runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have an some existing plugin DLLs written in C++ that export 1-40+ functions depending on exactly what functionality they provide.  The host application will test for the existence of the export and if it doesn't exist it will assume that the plugin does not provide that functionality.

I now want to write a shim DLL that sits between the host and a plugin.  The host will load the shim assuming it's a regular plugin DLL and the shim will in turn load the actual plugin.  The shim DLL must provide the exact same interface as the actual plugin since the presence of an exported function impacts the host's behavior.

I would like to have it so that when the host calls GetProcAddress it will look through the shim DLL into the actual plugin DLL and return a pointer to the function in the plugin DLL.  This could either be done when GetProcAddress is called, or when the dll is first loaded by somehow generating exports at load time.

My current thought is to use a hook library to hook calls to GetProcAddress and override them as appropriate, however the preference would be do to something less intrusive to the host process.

The alternative to doing this all dynamically is to do this in our build pipeline.  We would look at the plugin dll and get all of the exported symbols, then build a custom shim dll that replicates that interface.  It's possible, but it will also probably be quite a bit more work than just doing it at runtime.

Edit Feb. 1, 2014: There's no obviously supported way of doing this and I ran into issues hooking GetProcAddress so I ended up doing this via our build pipeline and forwarded exports.

Comment: what is the purpose of the shim DLL and why do you need it?  The idea you present is interesting however I do not understand why you go with the shim DLL versus just loading the actual one needed.

Comment: It's sounds a bit COM'esque. Any reason to not use COM, as it sounds like a good way to model your plugins?

Comment: This does seem COM like and seems like the kind of problem COM was designed to handle yet it also sounds a bit different.  It sounds like there is a standard interface with a list of functions that a plug-in may provide however individual plug-ins may or may not provide a specific function so the plug-in container performs a check to see which of the standard interface functions a specific DLL that is loaded will actually provide.  I assume the plug-in container has some kind of work around for missing functions.  This seems pretty straightforward so I am still curious as to why a shim DLL.

Comment: @RichardChambers: You are describing the behavior correctly.  The host is a 3rd party application so I have no control over the plugin architecture.  The actual plugin has a number of other dependencies, both other dlls and data files.  The shim is an attempt to package everything up into a single file and to give us a place to put some early initialization code (e.g. crash reporting systems) before the bulk of the plugin is loaded.

Comment: Too fuzzy to stick a fork into.  Automatic export forwarding from one DLL to another is described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx), "Export Forwarding" section.

Comment: The problem that I see is that the EXPORTs table is a compile/link time creation rather than run time and I am under the impression that GetProcAddress() looks at the table.  So this would seem to require your shim DLL to dynamically modify its EXPORTs table based on the plug-in while also supporting a kind of function call redirection to the functions provided by the plug-in.  A question: could you provide all of the standard functions in the interface and then return an error for those not supported by the plug-in DLL while redirecting the function call to the plug-in DLL for supported ones?

Comment: I would have to do more analysis into what the host program is expecting to know whether or not that would work.  It may be that the host program just patches any missing functions with a default version, but I could also imagine it doing something more complicated as an optimization.  I'm hesitant to rely on any observed behavior of the host program since it updates fairly regularly so I would be concerned that the underlying behavior might change.

@HansPassant: If I end up doing this at build time that looks like exactly what I would want to do.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not have a supporting DLL or static library with the functionality that you are proposing to put into the shim DLL and then just invoke that when the plug-in DLL is loaded?  So what would be the shim DLL is just one or more functions that are invoked when the plug-in DLL loads or is initialized.

Comment: The plugin package that I want to create will contain load-time DLLs that are not easily converted to be delay loaded and cannot be linked statically due to license restrictions.  Because of that there is no point (as far as I know) that I can run code in the plugin DLL to extract those dependencies and make sure the dependent DLLs can be found before the loader wants them.  By using a shim DLL with no dependencies other than kernel32 I can perform all of that setup before the actual plugin DLL is loaded.

Comment: Salvaged link from @MikeKaganski's answer: https://kobyk.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/unexporting-a-function-from-a-dll-at-runtime-by-name-obfuscation/ - has some interesting points, but generally it does exactly the opposite of what you are asking about. The answer itself might disappear as it contains this link only